# How to upgrade from 18.04.3 to the last 19.10

Tags: upgrade

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.3, with the backports PPA to get LTS.

I want to upgrade this system to the last version 19.10.

But... The automatic upgrading system just offers me to go to the 19.04 version.

How can I specifically get the last one (19.10) version?

Comment: Skipping releases is not tested, nor supported. Can you do it - Yes, but 18.04 was tested only going to 18.10 (not even 19.04), with 18.10 tested to 19.04, and 19.04 tested to go to 19.10.  There is a greater risk of problems when you skip releases, because QA-testers didn't try it and discover if it works, or has issues (causing documentation on mitigating issues to be written, or code tweaked to avoid issue).  It's possible as stated before, but includes additional risk.

Comment: You can re-install, to skip releases.  The 'something else' option with you re-using your existing partitions, no format will cause an upgrade to occur skipping releases. This option is tested for some flavors (I don't do QA for Ubuntu Studio so don't if they tested for it; I'm sure it'd work though as most flavors use ubiquity).  I've done this many times, though not with Ubuntu Studio (but believe it would work) and would have a higher chance than forcing a skipped release...

Comment: Do you have a need to use 19.10?  It only lasts 9 months before need to upgrade again.  18.04 studio will last at least till 2021(maybe 2023?).  Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 will be offered.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your data, brothers!!!